# React Big Calendar Event Hover modal opens

Tags: react-big-calendar

My problem is when hover on event how to set its position and it should be responsive i want to make it custom i don't want to use any library

For example if event is close to the border of react big calendar then the modal opens either on right or left it should place accordingly
can someone provide me proper logic for this functionality